# Can a <figure> element contain only a <figcaption> without an image?

Tags: html, semantic-web, w3c-validation, semantic-markup, figure

Is it semantic for a `<figure>` element to contain nothing but a `<figcaption>`? It does [validate](http://validator.w3.org)...

```
<figure>
  <img src="example.jpg">
  <figcaption>Image and caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <figcaption>Caption only</figcaption>
</figure>
```

In this context, it'd have ramifications for CSS styling:

```
figure figcaption { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `img` is not required in a `figure` element, it just happens to be common, and most examples that use `figcaption` also have an image.

> http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-figure-element
>
> The `<figure>` element can thus be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams, photos, code listings, etc, that are referred to from the main content
>   of the document, but that could, without affecting the flow of the
>   document, be moved away from that primary content, e.g. to the side of
>   the page, to dedicated pages, or to an appendix.
>
> http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-figcaption-element
>
> The `<figcaption>` element represents a caption or legend for the rest of
>   the contents of the figcaption element's parent figure element, **if
>   any**.

Note the "**if any**" part, which leads me to believe that content other than the `figcaption` may not exist and it will still be valid. However, as Alochi notes, it suggests a misuse of the element since there is no content for the caption to describe.

There *is* an example in the current specification example of non-image content being accompanied by a figcaption, so I think it's fair to assume it's perfectly OK to not have an image:

> Here, a part of a poem is marked up using figure.
>
> ```
> <figure>
>   <p>'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves<br>
>   Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;<br>
>   All mimsy were the borogoves,<br>
>   And the mome raths outgrabe.</p>
>   <figcaption>
>     <cite>Jabberwocky</cite> (first verse).
>     Lewis Carroll, 1832->  98
>   </figcaption>
> </figure>
> ```

Answer (score 5):

As Michael Malinovskij answered, A figure element should contain "flow content" as well as a figcaption.

[The HTML5 spec has this to say about flow content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#palpable-content)

> As a general rule, elements whose content model allows any flow
>   content or phrasing content should have at least one child node that
>   is palpable content and that does not have the hidden attribute
>   specified.
>
> This requirement is not a hard requirement, however, as there are many
>   cases where an element can be empty legitimately, for example when it
>   is used as a placeholder which will later be filled in by a script, or
>   when the element is part of a template and would on most pages be
>   filled in but on some pages is not relevant.

So not having anything other than the figcaption **is valid**, however unless you intend to fill in content later, it probably isn't conveying a useful or correct meaning, which could be characterised as **not semantic**.

Comment: Oh right, I got too caught up in the "without an image" part. A lone figcaption with no content makes no sense, right?

Comment: @WesleyMurch - It's hard to see when it would make sense, yes.

Comment: It's odd that the spec says "a caption for the rest of the contents of the figcaption element's parent figure element, ***if any***"... sounds like it's been considered and it's fair game to not have content other than a figcaption. I cannot see how that would make sense though.

Answer (score 2):

**Permitted contents for figure:**

- one figcaption element, followed by flow content
- flow content followed by an optional figcaption element

[(c) w3c/figure](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figure.html)

Comment: The "followed by flow content" part is greyed out on the W3C — curious if it's so clear-cut...